# Typescript Instead Of Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, frontend

Should i learn **typescript** instead of **javascript** for frontend frameworks ? I am learning angular js right now and there were many tutorials in typescript.

suggesstions please

Comment: SO is not the place for this kind of questions, we can help you with specific technical issues. This is mainly a matter of opinion and should be closed. :)

Comment: I would advise you to first learn plain vanilla JS, then TypeScript, and then Angular2. It may take some time but you'll have the good basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, learn javascript. Typescript is basically just javascript with types.
When you have learned javascript it will not be much of a step to learn the extras that is typescript.